# update username in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to have an option where the user can change his username in the mondgod database. I am using mongoose as ODM. 
The schema of my user is:

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        default: 9999999999
    },
    credits: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    password: String
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

userschema.js

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username: String,
        phone: {
            type: Number,
            default: 9999999999
        },
        credits: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        password: String
    });

    var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

in your app.js or index.js file :

```
var User=require('userschema.js');

app.post('/update/:id',function(req,res){
     var username=req.body.username;
     User.update({_id:req.params.id},{$set:{username:username}},function(err){
        if(!err){return res.json({status:"success",message:"username updated"});}
     });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Grab the User relating to whoever you want to edit, say user1
user1.password = YourHashingFunctionHere(newPass);
user1.Save();